# Не запускается сервер убунту после установки nginx

Tags: ubuntu, веб-программирование, nginx, isp

Установил nginx на ubuntu через ISP менеджер. (А точнее, запустил, он был отключен). После этого не работает доступ к ISP и к сайту. По ssh заходит. Что это может быть и как запустить сервер?

Comment: вероятно, всё-таки запускается: «По ssh заходит». из вопроса можно сделать предположение, что «раньше» сервер работал. может быть, на нём стоит, к примеру, *apache*, который и «работал» до включения nginx? уточните, пожалуйста, чего именно вы хотите добиться.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю что Ваша панель использовала какой-то веб-сервер, который "слушал" 80-й порт (или 443). После включения nginx, он начал слушать этот же порт, а веб-сервер панели при запуске видя что порт занят, не запускается. Именно поэтому Вы не можете зайти в панель. Сам сервер же работает, именно поэтому по ssh Вы подключаетесь.

Comment: Да, ISP поменял порт апача на 81, а Nginx не установил.